# Plotting the "AirPassengers" dataset in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, data-mining

I need help plotting the log of the number of passengers for each month and, from this plot, proposing a model for the logdata along the lines of regression. I'm new to R so this is a little troublesome for me. Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Also, R knows this dataset so using data("AirPassengers") will retrieve the data set.

Comment: Can you not just do `plot(log(AirPassengers))`?

Comment: Look at the examples in `?AirPassengers`

Answer (score 0):

You could start by following [many wonderful examples by Rob Hyndman](https://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/index.html)